# how is single-sign-on not a risk similar to spoofing and phishing?

Tags: single-sign-on

When you visit some websites, you can register and sign in as an authenticated member of some other organization (Google, Yahoo, etc).

What's to stop a malicious website from simply presenting a logon screen that purports to authenticate against those other sites, but is in actuality simply gathering usernames and passwords?

Could someone explain how such spoofing is prevented?

Comment: This is a great question.  If the site opens a new window, it can hide the address bar in some browsers (notably IE).  Then you fake the login screen of a Google sign in and the "authorize this application" pages.  The only downside is if the person enabled two-factor authentication on their account and is positive they are signed into Google.  The only defense is to be aware of what you are doing and to get browser vendors to help users avoid entering their passwords on foreign websites.  Of course, many people use the same password everywhere.

Comment: Continuing the line of thought of using the same password everywhere, it would be a LOT simpler to just ask the person for their e-mail address and password.  Nothing to spoof and would probably work just as well.  Relevant:  http://xkcd.com/792/

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) protocol.

Regarding what you ask, notice that you don't insert your credentials on the site you want to login but in a specific page of the provider offering OAuth authentication, you can't simply give to the user a fake page like you describe, or well... you could, but people familiar with that kind of authentication will notice (e.g. it asks me to login to google in a non-google hosted site?).

Comment: If I open a clean browser and go to a site with OAuth, it asks me to log in via Google as one of the options. I click the Google button, and am brought to a page that looks just like Google (it is really) which asks for email and password. But the original site could design an identical page and the only way to know would be by looking at the browser address bar at the URL. Seems like many people could be tricked by this if the original site had malice in mind.

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the address displayed by the browser and to the fact that being always over https the user can also verify the certificate. Yep, many people wouldn't notice, but it's not the objective of OAuth to make phishing harder, so i guess the answer to your question is that it doesn't even try to prevent phishing in any novel way.